Are multiple gets in a controller possible?
I am using ASP.NET Web API.  There is a Users Controller with the following two methods.
[HttpGet("{firstName}")]
public List<string> GetByFirstNameContains(string firstName)
{
    return new List<string>()
    {
        "F1", "F2", "F3"
    };
}
    
[HttpGet("{lastName}")]
public List<string> GetByLastNameContains(string lastName)
{
    return new List<string>()
    {
        "L1", "L2", "L3"
    };
}

The following error is generated:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple   endpoints. Matches:
GettingStartedAPI.Controllers.UsersController.GetByFirstNameContains (GettingStartedAPI)
GettingStartedAPI.Controllers.UsersController.Get (GettingStartedAPI)
GettingStartedAPI.Controllers.UsersController.GetByLastNameContains (GettingStartedAPI)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(Span1 candidateState) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, Span1 candidateState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Is there a way to have multiple methods in the same controller that will search by different fields?
This also falis:
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}

[HttpGet("{lastName}")]
public List<string> ArgleBargle(string lastName)
{
    return new List<string>()
    {
        "L1", "L2", "L3"
    };
}

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
GettingStartedAPI.Controllers.UsersController.Get (GettingStartedAPI)
GettingStartedAPI.Controllers.UsersController.ArgleBargle
(GettingStartedAPI)
I constructed the following hideous monstrosity, which kind of works.  Obvioudly, there must be a better way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[HttpGet("{field},{value}")]
public dynamic Get(UserNameFields field, string value)
{
    if (field == UserNameFields.FirstName)
    {
        return new List<string>()
        {
            "F1", "F2", "F3"
        };
    }
    else if (field == UserNameFields.ID)
    {
        return "value";
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<string>()
        {
            "L1", "L2", "L3"
        };
    }
}


You are using ASPNET.CORE API or ASPNET API?

The reason is you are using the type in the parameter you need to change in the param only then are you able to call the method. Like eg [HttpGet("FirstName/{firstName}")]

You are getting Asp.Net Core AmbiguousMatchException exception because the route pattern you defined for both functions use the same route pattern: [HttpGet("{parameter}")].
When you send a request, it won't be able to determine which of the methods to call.
I will suggest you differentiate the routes.
For the method GetByFirstNameContains, you can use:
[HttpGet("userbyfirstname/{firstName}")] 

and for the second method:
[HttpGet("userbylastname/{lastName}")]

I hope this helps

That worked for me.  I was mistaking GET for a category from a list and thought that the only accepted values were GET, PUT, etc.
